# Did Twilight know she was the second student before the incident with the crown?

Tags: my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim, equestria-girls

Twilight's personality in the Friendship is Magic show has always being shown as quite insecure. She constantly overthinks things and one of her biggest fears seems to be disappointing others (see: Lesson Zero for a prime example).

While this could just be her "personal flaw", many fans have tried to rationalize why she would have developed such an irrational fear, especially when interacting with Celestia - someone she has apparently known since she was little by the time the show starts. Some fans theorizes that this is just a side effect of realizing how much she needed friends and a constant fear of losing them, some others think there may be more to that.

The show Equestria Girl reveals that Twilight wasn't the first student Celestia had in that period - before her came Sunset Shimmer, who would fall into another world because of a mirror (that Stars Swirl told Celestia to dispose of/never use again multiple times). The official comic gives a short retelling of what actually happened and how Sunset "disappointed" Celestia expectations.

[image: Three panels from the official comic]

The comic above shows a very young Twily in the background behind Celestia and Sunset.

That made me wonder: are there any official sources that may point out if Twilight knew that Celestia had a previous student that "failed" before the incident with the crown happened in the first Equestria Girl movie? Knowing that someone "failed" before could be a quite plausible source for her fears.

The scene in the movie is sadly quite inconclusive: she just chases the thief without giving much importance to her identity, and even when Sunset reveals herself... it is Fluttershy who actually asks "who was that pony?".